# nested attributes and submitting the id as a different parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models, Races, Results, and Athletes. Atletes have many results, Races have many Results, and Results belong to both Athletes and Races. I also have Results as a nested attribute of Races. Here is my form partial for adding results to an existing race.

```
<%= form_for(@race) do |f| %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date %><br />
  <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
</div>

<% f.fields_for :results do |r| %>
<div class="field">
 <%= r.label :position %><br />
 <%= r.text_field :position %>
 <%= r.label :athlete_id %><br />
 <%= r.text_field :athlete_id %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I have to manually input the position of each athlete, and their respective ID's which is a real pain. I'd like to have the position as a hidden field and just type in the Athlete's name instead of the id integer. When I type the athletes name into the text input, how can I input that into the database as athlete_id instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the athletes already exist? If so, just do a `collection_select` on all the athletes where the value is the `athlete_id` and the text is the athlete's name. Then you can select whichever athlete you want.

Comment: yes the athletes already exist in the database. By using a collection_select, won't they have to be displayed via a select box rather than an text field?

Comment: Yes, which is much better in terms of UI. Why would you want to manually enter the name of an existing athlete when you could select it from a dropdown? This way you don't have to remember their names and you won't make any answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using the [rails auto_complete plugin](https://github.com/rails/auto_complete) to dynamically select the athlete you want to select.  You could then assign the selected athlete to a hidden field to ensure the id association happens properly, but still allow end user to type the name of an athlete and let rails scope the list of potential athletes however you'd like.